# NTLM authentication in Python

Tags: python, authentication, ntlm

I'm trying to implement NTLM authentication on IIS (Windows Server 2003) from Windows 7 with python. LAN Manager Authentication Level: Send NTLM response only.
Client machine and server are in the same domain.
Domain controller (AD) is on another server (also running Windows Server 2003).

I receive 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Could you please help me find out what is wrong with this code and/or show me the other possible directions to solve this problem (using NTLM or Kerberos)?

```
import sys, httplib, base64, string
import urllib2
import win32api
import sspi 
import pywintypes
import socket

class WindoewNtlmMessageGenerator:
    def __init__(self,user=None):
        import win32api,sspi
        if not user:
            user = win32api.GetUserName()
        self.sspi_client = sspi.ClientAuth("NTLM",user)   

    def create_auth_req(self):
        import pywintypes
        output_buffer = None
        error_msg = None
        try:
            error_msg, output_buffer = self.sspi_client.authorize(None)            
        except pywintypes.error:
            return None
        auth_req = output_buffer[0].Buffer
        auth_req = base64.encodestring(auth_req)
        auth_req = string.replace(auth_req,'\012','')
        return auth_req 

    def create_challenge_response(self,challenge):
        import pywintypes
        output_buffer = None
        input_buffer = challenge
        error_msg = None        
        try:
            error_msg, output_buffer = self.sspi_client.authorize(input_buffer)
        except pywintypes.error:
            return None
        response_msg = output_buffer[0].Buffer       
        response_msg = base64.encodestring(response_msg)
        response_msg = string.replace(response_msg,'\012','')
        return response_msg 


fname='request.xml'
request = file(fname).read()
ip_host = '10.0.3.112'

ntlm_gen = WindoewNtlmMessageGenerator()
auth_req_msg = ntlm_gen.create_auth_req()
auth_req_msg_dec = base64.decodestring(auth_req_msg)
auth_req_msg = string.replace(auth_req_msg,'\012','')
webservice = httplib.HTTPConnection(ip_host) 
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/idc/idcplg")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(request)) 
webservice.putheader('Authorization', 'NTLM'+' '+auth_req_msg) 
webservice.endheaders()
resp = webservice.getresponse()
resp.read()

challenge = resp.msg.get('WWW-Authenticate')
challenge_dec = base64.decodestring(challenge.split()[1])

msg3 = ntlm_gen.create_challenge_response(challenge_dec)
webservice = httplib.HTTP(ip_host) 
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/idc/idcplg?IdcService=LOGIN&Auth=Intranet")
webservice.putheader("Host", SHOD)
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(request))
webservice.putheader('Authorization', 'NTLM'+' '+msg3) 
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
webservice.putheader("SOAPAction", "\"\"")
webservice.endheaders()
webservice.send(request)
statuscode, statusmessage, header = webservice.getreply()
res = webservice.getfile().read()
res_file = file('result.txt','wb')
res_file.write(res)
res_file.close()
```

sspi.py is available here: 
https://ironpython.svn.codeplex.com/svn/IronPython_Main/External.LCA_RESTRICTED/Languages/IronPython/27/Lib/site-packages/win32/lib/sspi.py

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

```
import win32com.client

url = 'https://....'

h = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
h.Open('GET', url, False)
h.Send()
result = h.responseText
result
```

Comment: This answer is great. It works for me! I'm in a Windows environment and want to use domain authentication. It works!!!

Comment: what about a POST request? I wonder how I can handle the parameter in the Open function ...

Comment: how would I make this approach multi-thread proof as in a Flask environment for example?

Answer (score 16):

I've found out what was wrong.
I should keeping the connection alive.
That's the goods!
Now this problem is solved.

```
class WindoewNtlmMessageGenerator:
   def __init__(self,user=None):
       import win32api,sspi
       if not user:
           user = win32api.GetUserName()
       self.sspi_client = sspi.ClientAuth("NTLM",user)   

   def create_auth_req(self):
       import pywintypes
       output_buffer = None
       error_msg = None
       try:
           error_msg, output_buffer = self.sspi_client.authorize(None)             
       except pywintypes.error:           
            return None
       auth_req = output_buffer[0].Buffer
       auth_req = base64.b64encode(auth_req)
       return auth_req 


  def create_challenge_response(self,challenge):
      import pywintypes
      output_buffer = None
      input_buffer = challenge
      error_msg = None
      try:
          error_msg, output_buffer = self.sspi_client.authorize(input_buffer)
      except pywintypes.error:
          return None
      response_msg = output_buffer[0].Buffer        
      response_msg = base64.b64encode(response_msg) 
      return response_msg 


SHOD='qqq.yyy.dev'
answer='result.xml'
fname='request.xml'
try:
    a_file = open(fname, 'r')
    f=open(fname, 'r')
except IOError:
    sys.exit()
size = os.path.getsize(fname)
i=0
for line in f:
    i=i+1
count_string=i
f.close()
size=size-count_string+1


print '1' 

try:
    webservice = httplib.HTTPConnection(SHOD)     
    webservice.putrequest("POST", "/idc/idcplg?IdcService=LOGIN&Auth=Intranet")
    webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % 0)
    webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml")
    #webservice.putheader("User-Agent", 'Python-urllib/2.6')
    webservice.endheaders()
    res=webservice.getresponse()
except:
    msg= "unable to connect to URL:  "+ SHOD
    sys.exit()
if res.status == 401:
    auth_methods = [s.strip() for s in 
                    res.msg.get('WWW-Authenticate').split(",")]
    print auth_methods
if res.status <> 401:
    msg= "unable to connect to URL:  "+ SHOD_
    log_error(msg,answer)
    sys.exit()



print '2' 

ntlm_gen = WindoewNtlmMessageGenerator()
auth_req_msg = ntlm_gen.create_auth_req()
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/idc/idcplg?IdcService=LOGIN&Auth=Intranet")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % 0)
webservice.putheader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
#webservice.putheader("User-Agent", 'Python-urllib/2.6')
webservice.putheader('Authorization', 'NTLM'+' '+auth_req_msg) 
webservice.endheaders()
resp = webservice.getresponse()
resp.read()
print resp.status
challenge = resp.msg.get('WWW-Authenticate')
challenge_dec = base64.b64decode(challenge.split()[1])



print '3' 

msg3 = ntlm_gen.create_challenge_response(challenge_dec)
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/idc/idcplg?IdcService=LOGIN&Auth=Intranet")
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" %(size))
webservice.putheader("Connection", "Close")
webservice.putheader('Authorization', 'NTLM'+' '+msg3)
#webservice.putheader("User-Agent", 'Python-urllib/2.6') 
webservice.endheaders()
sable = a_file.read()     
webservice.send(sable)
resp = webservice.getresponse()
res=resp.read()
```

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted (click the green check mark next to it) so it doesn't get listed as an unanswered question.

Comment: How would this work for Linux? (I believe that some libraries are not available)

Comment: @Dimitris: it uses native Windows functions to authenticate against the domain - there's no way to do that from a non-Windows box. You'd have to reimplement the Netlogon protocol (MS-NRPC) natively, which involves implementing the underlying MS-RPC layer. Not a lot of fun.

Comment: @bobince, you *can* authenticate linux web services against an NTLM auth store using [PyAuthenNTLM2](https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2) and Apache... see [this blog](http://sys101.doloveyou.com/year/2013/articles/enable_NTLM_v2_on_apache.html) for an example

Comment: @Svetlana you should definitely mark this as an answer, the approach works nicely