# Automatic NTLM with python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tfs, ntlm

How can I use automatic NTLM authentication from python on Windows?

I want to be able to access the TFS REST API from windows without hardcoding my password, the same as I do from the web browser (firefox's network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris, for example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577331/308421) which works great for me because:

1. I'm only going to run it from Windows, so portability isn't a problem
2. The response is a simple json document, so no need to store an open session

It's using the WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 COM object to handle authentication natively:

```
import win32com.client
URL = 'http://bigcorp/tfs/page.aspx'    
COM_OBJ = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
COM_OBJ.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
COM_OBJ.Open('GET', URL, False)
COM_OBJ.Send()
print(COM_OBJ.ResponseText)
```

Comment: How do in install win32.com? its says no matching distribution found. My python is 3.8

Comment: @anandhu pip install pypiwin32

Answer (score 1):

I found solution here https://github.com/mullender/python-ntlm/issues/21

```
pip install requests
pip install requests_negotiate_sspi
```

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

GetUrl = "http://servername/api/controller/Methodname" # Here you need to set your get Web api url
response = requests.get(GetUrl, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
print("Get Request Outpot:")
print("--------------------")
print(response.content)
```

for request by https:

```
import requests
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

GetUrl = "https://servername/api/controller/Methodname" # Here you need to set your get Web api url
response = requests.get(GetUrl, auth=HttpNegotiateAuth(), verify=False)
print("Get Request Outpot:")
print("--------------------")
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos. Under the hood it's using https://github.com/mongodb-labs/winkerberos. The latter is marked as Beta, I'm not sure how stable it is. But I have requests-kerberos in use for a while without any issue.

Maybe a more stable solution would be https://github.com/brandond/requests-negotiate-sspi, which is using pywin32's SSPI implementation.

Answer (score -1):

NTLM credentials are based on data obtained during the interactive logon process, and include a one-way hash of the password. You have to provide the credential.

Python has [requests_ntlm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests_ntlm/) library that allows for HTTP NTLM authentication.

You can reference this article to access the TFS REST API :
[Python Script to Access Team Foundation Server (TFS) Rest API](http://techieroop.com/python-script-to-access-team-foundation-server-tfs-rest-api/)

If you are using TFS 2017 or VSTS, you can try to use [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) in a Basic Auth HTTP Header along with your REST request.

Comment: Thanks @Andy-MSFT, but the example you gave has the username and password hardcoded, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @liorda NTLM credentials are based on data obtained during the interactive logon process, and include a one-way hash of the password. You have to provide the credential.

Comment: So how can Firefox authenticate itself when accessing the TFS webpage? I have never explicitly log in or supplied my password.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479243/python-requests-ntlm-without-password

Comment: It should certainly be possible, I think you would start by calling [AcquireCredentialsHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374715(v=vs.85).aspx).  Firefox is open source so you could look and see what they've done.  Doing this from Python is liable to be awkward, though, unless someone has already built a solution for you.